# Jenkins Email Notification does not work

Tags: jenkins

I have a typical problem with jenkins email notification.
I have designed my build as follows

Step 1:Under Build Environment, i have set execute shell script on remote host

Step 2:Under Build , i have set execute shell script on remote host using ssh

Then under post build activities i have configured Email Notification but when Step 1 fails jenkins tries to continue with step 2 and does not send a failure message!

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest u use the plugin 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

This plugin having more control about the email content you are going to send out from Jenkins

FYI,

If your test script results is FAILED, the job might be still mark as PASS/UNSTABLE.

If you  test script FAILED to execute the test, then the job will mark as FAILED.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer at another thread: [jenkins do not send emails to multple recipients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24291167/jenkins-do-not-send-emails-to-multple-recipients/27117753#27117753)

It pertains to adding multiple recipients to mail notifications.