# jenkins do not send emails to multiple recipients

Tags: jenkins

I use Jenkins email-ext plugin to send emails when a build starts. 
When I specified only one recipient of such emails, everything worked smoothly - I got emails.

But when I specified more recipients Jenkins stopped sending emails, despite in builds' logs I can see they are being sent (I do not get them)

Isee the following message in a build's logs: "Sending email to: abc@abc.com def@abc.com". I do not see any errors there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

what worked for me was giving a comma and space between email addresses, such as:

```
x1@jenkins.com, x2@jenkins.com, x3@jenkins.com
```

XML representation of the Jenkins job looks as:

```
<maven2-moduleset plugin="maven-plugin@2.6">
...
 <reporters>
  <hudson.maven.reporters.MavenMailer>
   <recipients>x1@jenkins.com, x2@jenkins.com, x3@jenkins.com</recipients>
   <dontNotifyEveryUnstableBuild>false</dontNotifyEveryUnstableBuild>
   <sendToIndividuals>true</sendToIndividuals>
   <perModuleEmail>true</perModuleEmail>
  </hudson.maven.reporters.MavenMailer>
 </reporters>
</maven2-moduleset>
```

It has been sending mails all good with this.

Comment: thanks for response. I figured out that such a problem occurred when email addresses contained dots (e.g. a.b.c@gmail.com). After removing dots emails started to be sent correctly (gmail emails work with or without dots)

Comment: and what if my email isn't gmail? for me it isn't working. it have been 2 years passed, and i still face the same problem((

Answer (score 5):

I was also wondering why when one email was given it worked and when multiple email addresses were given separated by commas ',' it didn't. Managed to make it work.

This is what worked for me

```
pipeline {
        agent any

        environment {
            EMAIL_INFORM = 'abc@gmail.com;def@gmail.com'
        }


        stages {
        }

        post {

            success {  
                emailext body: 'Check console output at $BUILD_URL to view the results.', 
                        to: "${EMAIL_INFORM}", 
                        subject: 'Jenkins - Released $PROJECT_NAME - #$BUILD_NUMBER'
            }

        }
    }
```

You should use semi colons ';' rather than commas ',' when invoking "emailext" via declarative syntax in pipeline.

Hopefully it works now.

Comment: @t_sologub Please try my solution and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you select the option in the project configuration for email-ext to send an email for each child and not just the parent and then it should work.

Comment: please click the tick beside the answer if this works - i see that you are new here

Comment: could you please be more specific in description where to find this option? I do not see it in the project configuration..

Comment: In the job configuration enable "Editable Email Notification", then click on Advanced, and then just select "send to recipient list" and whatever other options you like

Comment: thanks, the problem is that I already did this earlier. The strangest thing is that if I leave only one email on the Project Recipient List I receive it.

Comment: this used to be a known issue in jenkins and has since been resolved in later releases which version are you using? suggest updating to 2.38.1

Comment: I am using 1.554.2 - this version if offered within the OpenShift PaaS. I think they do not give possibility to upgrade Jenkins version.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade the Email-ext plugin to 2.25

Here is the link http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/email-ext/2.25/

This worked for me.
Hope it helps!
Thanks :)

Comment: Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins -> Advanced -> Upload Plugin. Upload your .hpi file and restart jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else is having a similar problem, in my case I could not get it to send to multiple email addresses with dots in them. It turns out though, that there were some fields in the "Advanced settings" for the plugin that was causing issues.

Namely, that I did not have any triggers that would send to the recipient list. So make sure you have at least one trigger that will send to the recipient list if you want those emails sent out otherwise you will get an warning about trying to send to an empty list and no emails sent.

[image]